# What are the things to consider when i building dll ( which is implemented in VS C++ using OpenCv Library ) that going to integrate with c#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing

I have designed and implemented Algorithm in Vs c++ using OpenCv Library, now i need to check whether dll which i build is capable for integrating in c#.

1. What are the things to consider when i'm building dll ( which is implemented in VS C++ using OpenCv Library )
2. How to integrate dll in c# ( dll,which is implemented in VS C++ using OpenCv Library )

Comment: What do you exactly mean with integrate? You mean you built an unmanaged dll (in C++) and you want to use it in a managed application (in C#)? If so you need to export the functions in the dlls and interop them in the C# application. [Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dllimport)

Comment: @iVision what i meant is, i have an small algorithm in VS C++ ( used OpenCV library), now what are the things to consider while building a  dll which supports C# easier

Comment: One of the most important thing is the extern "c", it tells the C++ Compiler to not mangle the name, so you can interopt it in C#. [Whats the effect of Extern C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)

Comment: Yes What are the Basic Core OpenCv libs,dll's and headers required to run C++ dll [ used Opencv functions] in c# application??

Answer (score 0):

Any dll can be integrated in C#. However, if you want to make it easy for the implementer of the C# side, you can do some things:

Keep your interface clean C only. Primitive datatypes. Keep strings and structures to a minimum.

If that's not possible with your dll, consider writing a [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) wrapper. That will make it a LOT easier to consume your dll.

Comment: The biggest problem the author will have is the fact he is using OpenCV as this will require him to write a wrapper for any structures and datatypes that OpenCV uses in C#.

Comment: Uh... no? Only if he has those structures in his public interface.

Comment: nvoigt - Which is likely the case?

Comment: Maybe, but you made it sound like *using* OpenCV is a problem. It's not. Having *structures* (any kind, OpenCV or his own) in his interface will be a lot of work.

Comment: Its only a problem because he wants to PInvoke this library that he created.  It only adds additional challenges.

Comment: What are the Basic Core OpenCv libs,dll's and headers required to run C++ dll [ used Opencv functions] in c# application??